# Loading jCarousel with RequireJS + jQuery

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jcarousel

I'm trying to load a java plugin called [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) with RequireJS. My project structure looks like this:

```
[project root]
  assets
    app
    js
      app.js
      vendor
        jquery-2.1.0.js
        jquery.jcarousel-core.js
        require.js
```

I'm using [the shim config](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim) so I first load RequireJS like so:

```
    <script data-main="assets/js/app" src="assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

Then in app.js, I have this configuration of RequireJS:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "assets/js/vendor",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../../app"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.jcarousel-core.js": ["jquery-2.1.0"]
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

When I load the page up with this framework, all the scripts seem to load, but I get an error in the jcarousel code in the browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

That error seems to come from the line in the jQuery wherein -- and I can't remember the technical name for this procedure -- the '$' symbols is mapped to 'jQuery', e.g.:

```
        return Plugin;
    };
}(jQuery));  // THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
```

Any guidance here would be much appreciated!

**SOLUTION Based on Answer**

So the problem here was as @MakeeshSapkal put it, the line in my shim configuration for the jcarousel module should not have included .js.  So the configuration should have been:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "assets/js/vendor",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../../app"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.jcarousel-core": ["jquery-2.1.0"]
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, it seems that the '$' is not defined. When I do `$('.container').hide()` inside main.js, I get an error `Undefined TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `.js` from the shim configuration. :)

```
"shim": {
    "jquery.jcarousel-core": ["jquery-2.1.0"]
}
```

Hope this works!!!

Comment: That seems to have been it. Thanks!