# How to link jCarousel with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, jcarousel

I am attempting to load  [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) through RequireJS. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810326/loading-jcarousel-with-requirejs-jquery) but it is not working for me. My config is here:

```
baseUrl: './public/js', 
urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
paths: {
    bootstrap: './vendor/bootstrap',
    jquery: './vendor/jquery', 
},
shim: {
    bootstrap: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: '$.fn.popover'
    }, 
    jcarousel: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jCarousel'
    }
},
enforceDefine: true
```

I call carousel with code:

```
require(["jquery","jcarousel" ], function(  $, jcarousel_obj  ) {
 });
```

And I get Error: `No define call for jcarousel`.
So, what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem in your shim config.
Try to replace

```
//...
exports: 'jCarousel'
//...
```

on

```
exports: '$.jCarousel'
```

or

```
exports: '$.fn.jCarousel'
```

More information can be fount in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756567/loading-jquery-plugins-with-require-js)

Comment: Thanks, Yurii! 
This solution works: `exports: '$.jCarousel'`.